# pyodbc, error when inserting a string as parameter

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a problem when using pyodbc: the following code works:

```
Calc_Code='IHTLFRIDFPAR08NAP_KTS'
query = "select * from Product_Prices where Calc_Code='" + Calc_Code + "'"
curs.execute(query)
```

but the following code:

```
Calc_Code='IHTLFRIDFPAR08NAP_KTS'
query = "select * from Product_Prices where Calc_Code=?"
curs.execute(query,Calc_Code)
```

returns this error:
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

How can make the second code work? I would like to use the input as a parameter because this is more robust.

Thanks!!

Marc

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with the parameter statement, so some context is needed. Is the python executable exiting with this code, or just the script? What OS, python, and pyodbc version? A more complete code snippet would also be helpful. Lastly, congratulations on recognizing that parameters are a better solution -- many don't even get that far.

Comment: What is the column data type? Does it happen to be char/varchar(1024)?